# Need to know the regex format that shouldnt allow a particular string

Tags: regex

I need to know the regex that doesnot allow the string "delete all" but it should accept everything "delete" followed by anything.

For example, it should not allow "delete all" but it should allow "delete 1", "delete xyz", etc...

Comment: java....i dono exactly. i'm entirely new to regex

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookahead `/delete(?!\s*all)/` will match "*delete*" in "*delete 1*", but not in "*delete all*".

For more details read http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html